# Counting the occurence of a specific string in a csv file

Tags: python, file, csv, for-loop, count

Hi I have a file in which I need to count how many times the word 'Methadone' and 'Co-Codamol' appear. It seems to print '0' when in fact in this particular file the total times methadone and co-codamol occur is 9 times. Here is what the file looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUdJt.png

and here is my code:

```
import csv
import collections
number = collections.Counter()
with open('C:\Users\Desktop\practice jan.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=','):
        number[row[1]] += 1
print 'Number of prescriptions is %s' % number['Methadone' + 'Co-Codamol']

>> Number of opioid prescriptions is 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file and count the number of occurences of your string:

```
with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    print(content.count("Methadone"))
```

As long as your file is not too large, this will do the work.

Comment: The files will be up to 4 million rows x 120 files... am I going to need to do each seperately? - This current file is just a practice one

Comment: I just tried this with a 2GB file - and it crashed massively :( How can I stop this happening?

Comment: You can read the file line by line and count the occurence in each line. Then you can accumulate this over all lines to get the total number. In order to count the occurences in multiple files, first get a filelist using for example `glob` and then count it for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what context you're trying to do this in, but if you can use grep it's very simple:

grep -o string file | wc -l

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'Methadone' and 'Co-Codamol' are two different drugs, I suggest you to replace your last line with:

```
print 'Number of prescriptions is %s' % (number['Methadone'] + number['Co-Codamol'])
```